# Regex java keyboard input

Tags: java

I want to check the keyboard input in order to validate a car plate format

```
        String formatoPatente = "[A-Za-z]{3}[\\-\\s][0-9]{3}";
    String patente,marca;
    int añoPatentamiento;
    double kilometraje,tamañobaul;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la patente del automovil");
    patente=teclado.nextLine();
    boolean valido = patente.matches(formatoPatente);
    while(!valido){
        System.out.println("Formato invalido de patente. Intente nuevamente.");
        patente=teclado.next();
    }
```

I think the regex is ok, but still doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "regex is ok"? What is it supposed to verify? Elaborate.

Comment: 3 letter capital or not, an space and 3 numbers

Comment: You can have just 3 numbers without any alphabets?

Comment: this is an example the correct format.
AAA 111 or
bbb 222

Comment: I assume these are two examples. Right?

Comment: Exactly. I should ask for input until the user types
three letters (capital or not)
a space
and three numbers

Comment: Try to trim an input before mathches call, it could contain some special characters

Comment: I think some responders have figured out the problem, but next time **please do not post questions that say "It doesn't work".**  Let us know **what** it's doing wrong, i.e. what input you give it, what it outputs, and why the output is wrong.  That's important information.  Please don't keep it a secret from us.

Answer (score 0):

next() will read characters till a space is found. Thus the input numbers may not be read post the space provided. see if the below code helps where input is read from nextLine which reads the complete line itself.

```
   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String formatoPatente = "[A-Za-z]{3}[\\-\\s][0-9]{3}";
    String  inputData, marca;
    int añoPatentamiento;
    double kilometraje, tamañobaul;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la patente del automovil");
    Pattern patente = Pattern.compile(formatoPatente);
    Matcher matcher;
    boolean notMatched = true;
        while(notMatched) {
            inputData = teclado.nextLine();
            matcher = patente.matcher(inputData);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Match Found");
                notMatched = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Formato invalido de patente. Intente nuevamente.");
            }
    }
```